# ActionBar/Toolbar gets overlapped on DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, dialog, toolbar, android-appcompat

I took up on the tips in google's Material Design on Dialogs.
For my app, I am looking at a Navigation Drawer Activity that swaps between a bunch of Fragments that edit the toolbar seeing fit.

What I want is a Fullscreen Dialog that has a "close" button and a save button on the corners of the toolbar. You can see it here:
https://material.io/design/components/dialogs.html#full-screen-dialog

I'm following android developer's guide on it:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs

Problem: When setting the toolbar inside the dialog works, but it completely messes with my toolbar for the next fragments. As soon as the dialog sets the toolbar, then things like Activity.setTitle() don't change the toolbar's title. Also, the overriden method OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater) it's not called so I can't even inflate views on the menu (toolbar) after the dialog triggering.

I suspect it's because I change the activity's toolbar but I don't know how to do it otherwise. Inside the fragment that calls the dialog I have:

```
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            AddListDialogFragment newFragment = new AddListDialogFragment();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            transaction.add(R.id.drawer_layout, newFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Here is the dealbreaker: Inside the DialogFragment I have this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_list, container, false);

    Toolbar toolbar = rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbarDialog);
    toolbar.setTitle("Create List");


    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBar actionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);
    }
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    return rootView;
}
```

It's important to note that R.id.toolbarDialog is the specific id of the toolbar only used in the DialogFragment's xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarDialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your content here"/>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The normal toolbar has another id.

As I said, I believe the problem stems from `((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`, since when you set a supportActionBar, it doesn't come back to the one before. I can't think of a workaround.
How do I save a copy and return to the original SupportActionBar when the Dialog closes?

Thanks.

Comment: When you use `onCreateOptionsMenu` do you have the call to `super` in there? Want to figure out why `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

Comment: No. I should? Why calling a super inside the onCreateOptionsMenu change anything when (after the dialog) the method is not triggered at all?

Comment: I just added it on both methods and nothing changed.

Comment: I didn't say that you should add it. If you are using Fragments then your `onCreateOptionsMenu` should only contain `inflater.inflate...`. If I understand you correctly you want a custom toolbar for each fragment. Put `setHasOptionsMenu` in `onCreate`, and you should also `seSupportActionBar`.

Comment: I have a custom toolbar for some fragments. In the fragments i setHasOptionsMenu in onCreateView of the ones that I edit said toolbar. However since it's a NavigationDrawerActivity (which i only have one activity for all fragments) I don't setSupportActionBar in any of them, only in the dialog. After that it fucks up the toolbar from my main activity as I said.

Comment: if I have to use setsupportActionbar on each fragment, how do i get the toolbar for the parameter? If I use getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar); makes the drawer static (doesn't toggle the drawer)

Comment: I understand, it's because you have one toolbar in your activity for all fragments, I was mentioning the case where you have a toolbar for each fragment in each of their XML files. I don't fully understand the problem. So the DialogFragment changes the Toolbar but when you come back to your activity it doesn't change back?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172406/discussion-between-datasetter-and-lieforbananas).